# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, dex

I am getting "unable to merge dex" error while deploying the app on real device. I have also upgraded my compile and target sdk to andorid-p.

Here is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-28'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cofoz.cofoz"
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.1.5"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        preDexLibraries true
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
            shrinkResources true
            //Other parameters
            //debuggable false
            //jniDebuggable false
            //renderscriptDebuggable false
            //signingConfig playStoreConfig //Add your own signing config
            //pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            //zipAlignEnabled true

            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Disables PNG crunching for the release build type.
            crunchPngs false

        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'

    //implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

    // Required only if Facebook login support is required

    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.DanielMartinus:Stepper-Touch:0.6'

    //implementation 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6'

    //implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'

    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    //implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    //implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

    //implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

    //implementation'io.salyangoz.updateme:updateme:0.1.0'

    //implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:v1.4.0'

    // Shimmer

    //implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'

    //implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    //implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.3'

    //implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:4.13.1'


    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-beta2"
    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.4.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

    //implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.2.0@aar') { transitive = true }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried many things such as clean and rebuild project etc.
I am not getting any error while building it but when I deploy the app to real device then only the error occures.

Comment: Please post the exception's full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I added Firestore to my project.

Make sure you have the `multidex` library implemented (I see you have an old version commented out):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Also, you implement both `support-compat` and `support-v4`. `support-v4` already includes everything `support-compat` does, so you have a duplicate implementation. Please clean up your dependencies and remove any you don't need.

Comment: It did not work man. I am also getting this error "Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}"

Comment: Well for starters, you really need to update your dependencies. API 28 support libraries are on `rc02` now, not `alpha01`. And check for any red underlines in your dependencies as well. Also check your project-level Gradle file for outdated dependencies.

Comment: removed the dependency as you said but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Clean up the rest of your dependencies too.